# Objective C - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, recursion, exc-bad-access

My program uses recursion. I can't show you code, because it's huge.

If I use recursion to long I get this

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0xb03b1fcc)`

And when I try to print object with this error, I get

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0xb03b1fcc). The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.`

What does this mean? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very common error and usually it's because of a null reference, meaning your object has a 'nil' value when you try to use it. It's very hard to help you unless you do show some code.

Comment: The first thing I would check would be whether the object being recursed on could potentially be null and whether the code checks to see if it's null before operating on it.

Comment: You can use stepper to find which line leads to it, then post that part of your code.

Comment: The problem is not that something is nil; nil will not cause a bad access. Your problem is that an object has been over-released. The first major question is are you using ARC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My program uses recursion. I can't show you code, because it's huge.

That, right there, is most likely the source of your problem.  Specifically, you've overflowed the stack (i.e. recursed too deeply with too much junk on the stack).

In general, deep recursion should be avoided on most C based systems as the stack depth is generally limited.

You should consider refactoring away from using recursion.

Comment: how to thrashed overflowed stack.

Answer (score 1):

This means you're trying to access memory at address `0xb03b1fcc` but don't have permission to do so. Usually this is a problem with memory allocation/objects references but if you say that it occurs only when you're doing a deep recursion, it might just be that you've had a stack overflow (trying to access memory on the stack beyond its limit).

The debugger should point you to the exact instruction that causes the bad memory access, however if the problem is indeed recursion you will just need to use less stack memory and/or reduce your recursion depth.

Comment: I believe `0xb03b1fcc` is on the stack and, thus, you can more strongly assert that this is a stack overflow.